# How to pass an array from a server with SignalR and present the result using Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am playing with SignalR and KnockoutJS and can't seem to find a simple way to get an array from the database presented using the MVC4 framework.

I have no problem sending a single object from the server - but when I try to send an array I get stuck.  Hopefully someone with more experience can spot the probably obvious mistakes I am making, and show how this should be done (JavaScript is not my strong side). The problem as far as I can understand is the mapping of the data passed from the server.  Any help is much appreciated!

The SignalR Hub (orders is a simple table with Id and Name)

```
public class feedHub : Hub
{
    private dataContext db = new dataContext();
        public void GetAll()
        {
        var orders = db.orders.ToArray();
        Clients.getData(orders);
        }
}
```

Simple HTML code to present the orders;

```
<div id="Demo"> 
  <div data-bind="foreach: orders">
    <div data-bind="html: Id"></div>
    <div data-bind="html: Name"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">   

    var viewModel = {
       orders: ko.observableArray(orders)
    };


    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#Demo")[0]);

    $(function () {        
        // Client side version of the feebHub class
        var hubcon = $.connection.feedHub;

        // getData called from server 
        hubcon.getData = function (data) { viewModel.orders(data) };

        // Start connection and call getAll
       $.connection.hub.start(function () { hubcon.getAll(); });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. Just use `ko.observableArray()`, i.e. without the parameter
2. Put the call to `ko.applyBindings` inside your ready function, e.g. just before you get your hub reference

That should be enough to get it working.  At least, it works me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69BVQ/1/) which I based on your code.

One further point though ... you are passing plain JSON objects to KO (i.e. inside your observable array).  This is like data-binding in C# against some classes that do **not** implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  IOW the binding will work properly once and changes in the objects will never get reflected on the UI.    If you want SignalR to feed changes into your objects, then they will need to have observable properties and you might want to look into [the KO mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

Comment: Thanks John, this was the pointers I needed to get it up and running.  Was quite frustrated over this, so your help is much appreciated! Also the first time I posted a problem on Stackoverflow, great way to get help thanks to people like you. Again thanks for helping out!